# Beginner real analysis help

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I have a little problem that I can't seem to get right.

How do I show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4^n}{n! + 3^n}$ converges. I have tried using the ratio test on this, but I get something that just doesn't seem to workout.

I would be grateful for any advice on how to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use the comparison test.  I think we can agree that $\frac{4^n}{n! + 3^n} < \frac{4^n}{n!}$ for all $n$, correct?  Then we have that

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4^n}{n! + 3^n} \;\; < \;\; \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4^n}{n!}.
$$

The series on the right converges to something quite familiar.

Comment: Not really familiar.... sorry, you should be more careful what you claim.

Comment: I don't understand your critique.  Please explain.

Comment: It converges by  ratio test... but saying that "the right converges to something quite familiar" is false.  If its familiar then what does it equal?

Comment: The series converges to $e^4 -1$.  I was trying to leave it open-ended so that the OP might be able to find out for themselves.

Comment: ..... I had a blonde moment.

Comment: We all do from time-to-time :)

Answer (score 0):

$$0\leq\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{4^n}{n!+3^n}\leq\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{4^n}{n!}=e^4-1.$$